# Python mock patch argument `new` vs `new_callable`

Tags: python, mocking

From the documentation http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html

```
patch(target, new=DEFAULT, spec=None, create=False, spec_set=None, autospec=None, new_callable=None, **kwargs)
```

> If new is omitted, then the target is replaced with a MagicMock. If patch is used as a decorator and new is omitted, the created mock is passed in as an extra argument to the decorated function. If patch is used as a context manager the created mock is returned by the context manager.
>
> new_callable allows you to specify a different class, or callable
>   object, that will be called to create the new object. By default
>   MagicMock is used.

I am trying to understand the differences between the two, and what situation to use `new_callable` instead of `new`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`new` is an actual object; `new_callable` is a callable used to create an object. The two cannot be used together (you either specify the replacement or a function to create the replacement; it's an error to use both.)

```
>>> foo = 6
>>> with mock.patch('__main__.foo', new=7):
...   print foo
...
7
>>> with mock.patch('__main__.foo', new_callable=lambda : 8):
...   print foo
...
8
```

When `new` is `mock.DEFAULT`, the mock object is a `MagicMock` instance precisely because the default value of `new_callable` is `MagicMock`.

Comment: Another useful difference is that if you use the `new_callable` parameter on a decorator, the mock is passed to the method, or every test method in the class if you decorated a class. If you use the `new` parameter, it is not (presumably because you could as easily maintain a reference to the object in scope).

Answer (score 6):

**[EDIT]**
In that answer I missed the most important thing that `new` take an object and `new_callable` a callable (the factory) as said correctly by @chepner. I don't remove it because it contains either some useful notes.

By digging the code https://code.google.com/p/mock/source/browse/mock.py#1266 is clear that by `new` you cannot set the attributes by nominal arguments and use `spec` or `spec_set` because it will raise a `TypeError` exception.

`new_callable` can be a subclass of `NonCallableMock` itself and you can use all mock facilities in patch definition.

Sure that behavior is really not documented and also in http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/changelog.html#version-0-8-0 you can't find much more than.

> New new_callable argument to patch and patch.object allowing you to
>   pass in a class or callable object (instead of MagicMock) that will be
>   called to replace the object being patched

Anyway you cannot use something like that to create a `YourMockSubclass` that have the `myobject` signature

```
@patch("mymodule.myobject", new=YourMockSubclass(), spec=myobject)
```

but in that case you must use `new_callable`:

```
@patch("mymodule.myobject", new_callable=YourMockSubclass, spec=myobject)
```

So you have to use `new_callable` every time you need a non-MagicMock mock for your mock.

**IMHO the only useful use is mocking property.**